# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to change Bool property

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm trying to change a Bool property and am receiving an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I'm using XCode 6 and Swift.

The `note` property saves fine but the `completed` property throws the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error

[image]

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Task: NSManagedObject
{

    @NSManaged var note: String!
    @NSManaged var completed: Bool

}
```

Changing out the property routine

```
    // taskObject is an instance of Task()

    // Set the completed flag
    taskObject.completed = true // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Comment: I would try using `NSNumber(bool:true)` instead of `true`. CoreData is based on sqlite which does not have a bool type, it uses 0/1 numbers internally.

Comment: This will product a type error since NSNumber doesn't follow the `@NSManaged completed: Bool` type

Comment: Your variable should be an `NSNumber` unless you explicitly checked "use scalar values for primitives" when creating your core data model file.

Comment: Looks like changing that the data type to `NSNumber` in the subclass worked.

Comment: See this post, similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333507/swift-coredata-can-not-set-a-bool-on-nsmanagedobject-subclass-bug?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, the solution is indeed to use NSNumber in the @NSManaged property. Additionally you could define a computed Bool property so that you can work with the scalar Boolean in your business logic and not with the NSNumber.

```
var isCompleted: Bool {
get {
    return completed == NSNumber(bool: true)
}
set {
    completed = NSNumber(bool: newValue)
}
}
```

Comment: Hey, i have the same problem , but while retrieving the bool. It is stored as Integer while it shows of type bool in the modal. I need to show something based on the bool/integer value. Is this something that you know? `commentsList[indexPath.row].isSigned` gives Bad_access Exception.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just considering filing a bug as I have the same issue but if your really want to use Bool still then a workaround is to use this method:

```
setValue(true, forKey: "completed")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had almost this exactly problem.

Boolean works in Core Data.

The problem I had was in the Core Data Editor under 'CONFIGURATIONS' and 'C' Default. I did not have my entity linked to the correct class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a swift `Bool` with an NSManagedObject - no need for the `NSNumber` nonsense. But you need to make sure that in the core data editor, the class is not empty. Enter your objects' name.

[image: do not leave this empty]