# How to use Core Data Integer 64 with Swift Int64?

Tags: core-data, swift, ios8

I have a CoreData attribute on an entity on which I want to store integer values larger than `Int32.max` and `UInt32.max`. The value is used as an index, so lookup performance matters. So I've opted to use `Integer 64` as datatype in CoreData.

Now I'm struggling on how to store an Int64 on my entity instance. See also the following different approaches I've tried.

Use `NSNumber`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Node : NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id : NSNumber
}

node.id = Int64(1)
> 'Int64' is not convertible to 'NSNumber'
```

Use `NSInteger`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Node : NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id : NSInteger
}

node.id = Int64(1)
> 'Int64' is not convertible to 'NSInteger'
```

Use `Int64`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Node : NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id : Int64
}

node.id = Int64(1)
> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=...)
```

How should the attribute be defined / assigned in order to use 64 bit integers?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can define the "Integer 64" attribute as `NSNumber` in the managed object subclass:

```
@NSManaged var id : NSNumber
```

Setting a value:

```
let value:Int64 = 20000000000000000
node.id = NSNumber(longLong: value)
```

Retrieving the value:

```
let value:Int64 = node.id.longLongValue
```

Note that `long long` is a 64-bit integer on both the 32-bit and the 64-bit architecture.

---

Defining the property as

```
@NSManaged var id : Int64

// ...
node.id = Int64(...)
```

*should* also work, because Core Data supports scalar accessor methods for primitive
data types. The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception when assigning a value looks to me
like a bug in the Swift compiler or runtime. A similar problem for a Boolean property
is reported here

- [EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to change Bool property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112250/exc-bad-access-error-when-trying-to-change-bool-property)

where a `NSNumber` property is reported to work, but the scalar `Bool` property
causes the same exception.

Comment: Using your proposed workaround `NSNumber(longLong: value)` worked. I agree with you that the latter is probably a bug in Swift.

Comment: The issue with Int64 causing traps on 32 bit architectures (18113807) has been fixed in Xcode 6.1 beta.

Comment: do you think it is fixed in xcode 6.1 beta I am still facing this issue in xcode 11.2.1