# Why am I getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when converting to a float or a double? (In Swift)

Tags: nsstring, double, swift, textfield

I am trying to store some values from textfields as doubles and floats and I cannot get past the above error.

I have defined the property to match the attribute in my cordata database:

```
@NSManaged var custjobcost: Double
```

When I am mapping the properties in order to save them, I am using the following code, but it will not accept it - on runtime, I get the error indicated above.

```
newItem.custjobcost = (textfield.text as NSString).doubleValue
```

I have also the same thing, but with float and floatvalue instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Core Data Integer 64 with Swift Int64?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350686/how-to-use-core-data-integer-64-with-swift-int64) - In short: Use NSNumber. The scalar accessor methods of Core Data do currently not work with Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
newItem.custjobcost = textfield.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().doubleValue
```

Comment: Why should that help?

Comment: It helps because `bridgeToObjectiveC()` gets the `NSString` version of the `String`, and that has a valid `doubleValue` method. Same thing works for all the other scalar accessors of Strings, like `length` and the other `*Value`s.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but I tried this already and the same error - it won't let me past it!

Comment: `textField.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().doubleValue` does the same as `(textfield.text as NSString).doubleValue` which is used in the question.