# ManagedObjectModel subclass doesn't work in Swift

Tags: core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectmodel

To summarize what I've done:

1. Created a project named 2048.
2. Created a subclass of NSManagedObject

   ```
   class BestScore: NSManagedObject {
       @NSManaged var bestScoreModel: BestScoreModel
       func update(score: Int) {
           self.bestScoreModel!.score = score
       }
   }
   ```
3. Created a subclass of NSManagedObjectModel

   ```
   class BestScoreModel: NSManagedObjectModel {
       @NSManaged var score: Int
   }
   ```
4. Created a Data Model under Core Data tab. Named the file as 2048.xcdatamodeld. Added an entity BestScoreModel with one attribute "score" and defined the type as Integer 16. Besides, I also updated the class of the entity as 2048.BestScoreModel according to the [official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html).
5. In the controller class, I added following variables

   ```
   class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

       var bestScore: BestScore?

       @lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
           let serviceName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary.objectForKey("CFBundleName") as String
           let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(serviceName, withExtension: "momd")
           let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
           if model == nil {
               println("Error initilizing model from : \(modelURL)")
               abort()
           }
           let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
           let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
           let storeURL = (urls[urls.endIndex-1]).URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(serviceName).sqlite")
           var error: NSError? = nil
           var store = coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil, error: &error)
           if store == nil {
               println("Failed to load store at \(storeURL) with error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
               abort()
           }
           var context = NSManagedObjectContext()
           context.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
           return context
       }()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           let entity: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("BestScoreModel", inManagedObjectContext: context)
           bestScore = BestScore(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
           bestScore.update(0)
       }
   }
   ```

The application was built successfully but when I ran the simulator, it threw exceptions with below

```
    2014-07-13 00:56:59.944 2048[76600:4447122] -[NSManagedObject update:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bc55d20
    2014-07-13 00:56:59.948 2048[76600:4447122] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject update:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bc55d20'
```

I'm completely new to iOS developing and have no experience before. I wanna take Swift as an opportunity for start writing apps without learning objective-c. Please let me know if I misconfigured anything.

Appreciate for your help.

PS: I get the implementation of the managed object context from [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2014/06/08/the-core-data-stack-in-swift/). Big thanks to the author!

Answer (score 2):

The `NSManagedObjectModel` describes the collection of all entities used in your application, and there is usually no reason to subclass it.

I would suggest that you use the *same name* for both the entity and the corresponding
managed object subclass. (This is also what Xcode does when you create an Objective-C managed object subclass)

The Swift managed object subclass (which Xcode cannot create automatically yet)
would simply look like this:

```
class BestScore: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var score: NSNumber
}
```

I have used the `NSNumber` type instead of `Int16`, because scalar accessor methods in Swift managed
object subclasses do not yet work correctly, compare [How to use Core Data Integer 64 with Swift Int64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350686/how-to-use-core-data-integer-64-with-swift-int64).

A new BestScore object would then be created with

```
bestScore = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("BestScore", inManagedObjectContext: context) as BestScore
```

and you can access its properties directly, without the need for an `update()` function:

```
bestScore!.score = 0
```

*Additional Remarks:* It would make sense to define the `bestScore` property as an 
*implicitly unwrapped* optional, because you expect it to have a value after
`viewDidLoad:`. That saves you many explicit unwrappings later:

```
var bestScore: BestScore!
```

Also, if the application is run a second time, you probably want to reload the
existing best score, instead of creating a new object.
That means that you have to execute a fetch request first, and insert a new
object only if none was found:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BestScore")
var error : NSError?
let result = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

if !result || result.count == 0 {
    // Error or no object found: create new one:
    bestScore = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("BestScore", inManagedObjectContext: context) as BestScore
    bestScore.score = 0
} else {
    // Use existing object:
    bestScore = result[0] as BestScore
}
let score = bestScore.score.integerValue // NSNumber --> Integer
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried with your advice and now I'm able to instantiate the managed object context. But I would still get an exception when calling NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(). The thread exception is: `thread #1: tid = 0x3b9e05, 0x00000001001e4dfa libswift_stdlib_core.dylib swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 106, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)`

Comment: @Bing: I think I tested the code before posting it and it worked. Have you set both "Entity" and "Class" of your entity to "BestScore" in the Core Data model inspector?

Comment: If you mean 2048.xcdatamodeld file, yes, I've renamed the entity as BestScore and the class as 2048.BestScore. I also tried the class as BestScore. Both cases threw the same exception. :( I must be missing something and I feel it is very hard to debug in swift, not sure about Objective-C though

Comment: I use my original way (creating NSEntityDescription and BestScore separately) and it succeeds! But now I'm facing another exception when I try to call the update method. Following your suggestion by changing the score value directly did work but I still want to get the update method working since this is mainly for learning purpose. The exception I got is `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject updateBestScore:withBestLevel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bf39e50'` Big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify module name for entity in your `.xcdatamodeld` file. See **Implementing Core Data Managed Object Subclasses** section in ["Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.1)"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-ID86) book for detailed description were you can find it.