# bad exception when inserting new entity

Tags: ios, exception, core-data, exc-bad-access

I have an exception bad access code 2, when i am inserting new entity in core data.

```
    class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, fuel_id: Int, fuel_name: String, price: Double) -> Fuel

    {
        var fuel = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("GasStation", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as Fuel //exception - EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT

        moc.performBlockAndWait { () -> Void in
            fuel.fuel_id = fuel_id
            fuel.fuel_name = fuel_name
            fuel.price = price

        }

//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
//            fuel.fuel_id = fuel_id
//            fuel.fuel_name = fuel_name
//            fuel.price = price
//
//        })


        return fuel
    }
```

and

```
if let prices = info["prices"] as? NSArray {
     for price in prices {
     let fuelId : Int = price["fuel_id"] as Int
     var fuelPriceString : String = price["price"] as String
     let fuelName : String = price["fuel_name"] as String
     var fuelPrice : Double = NSString(string:fuelPriceString).doubleValue


     println(managedObjectContext)

     var fuel =
Fuel.createInManagedObjectContext(managedObjectContext!,fuel_id: Int64(fuelId), fuel_name: fuelName, price:fuelPrice)// exception
     fuelSet.append(fuel)
          }
     println(fuelSet)
}
```

I tried to see if context is nil, but it has address. i read some articles about zombies tool for detecting what exact exception u have and why, but there is no instructions. Can someone help me, cause i am really stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350686/how-to-use-core-data-integer-64-with-swift-int64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure one of the following:

- your managedObjectContext is a NSMainQueueConcurrencyType one (rather
  than NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType )
- Perform the changes in a performBlock or performBlockAndWait

So:

```
var fuel
moc.performBlockAndWait { () -> Void in
    fuel = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("GasStation", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as Fuel
    fuel.fuel_id = fuel_id
    fuel.fuel_name = fuel_name
    fuel.price = price
}
return fuel
```

(hopefully easy to translate to Swift) Basically, if you're in a private queue context, make sure you don't access it from the main thread (e.g. UI code etc), this applies to reads and writes. Be careful reading from the newly created object back in the main thread if you created it in a private queue.

I recommend to spend a bit of time reading about it and playing around seeing where the pain-points are. It will save you time in the long run!

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-concurrency--cms-22131
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html

Comment: you are right, my exc no is on next line. so what is the solution?

Comment: unfortunately , i tried both of this, and it didnt help to solve my problem

Comment: it still bombs out on fuel.id = fuel_id, or fuel.name (whichever is first)? or somewhere else?

Comment: added code on the top of post. it runs all cycle, prints all data that i tried to save in for-cycle, and bombs with exc

Comment: another edit... possibly beyond this it could be something Swift-y that I don't know about. But it does look a lot like core data thread/queue errors that I get when I rush through things.